# Select last day of ISO-8601 week (and retain only year and week as object)

Tags: python, pandas, date

We have this `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date': [pd.Timestamp('2020-12-26'), # week 52 of year 2020
                 pd.Timestamp('2020-12-27'), # last day of week 52 of year 2020
                 pd.Timestamp('2021-03-10'), # week 10 of year 2021
                 pd.Timestamp('2022-01-03'), # first day of week 1 of year 2022
                 pd.Timestamp('2022-01-09')], # last day of week 1 of year 2022
        'value' : [15, 15.5, 26, 36, 36.15]

})
```

We want a new `df` that looks so:

```
      date  value
0   202052  15.50
1   202201  36.15
```

In other words we need to:

1. convert 'date' to format year/week number (and store result as
   an object)
2. select only rows which date correspond to the last
   day of the week

Note both (1) and (2) need to be done following ISO-8601 definition of weeks. Actual dataset has thousands of rows.

How do we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work directly on the series by using the `dt` call on the column to transform the format of the date. To find if it is the last day of the week, Sunday corresponds to `7` so we can do an equality check.

```
iso = df.date.dt.isocalendar()
mask = iso.day == 7
df.loc[mask].assign(date=iso.year.astype(str) + iso.week.astype(str).str.rjust(2, "0"))

     date  value
1  202052  15.50
4  202201  36.15
```

Comment: nice! how do we do to keep initial '0' for weeks that have single digits, though? So that '20221' in your solution is displayed as '202201'?

Comment: updated, just need to use the `str` call on that column followed by the `rjust` method

Comment: You don't need to go through `isocalendar` - the same can be achieved with the builtin Timestamp functions `year`, `weekofyear` and `day_of_week` (and a `mask` `== 6`).

Comment: I updated the `mask` since you are right the math was not needed, but you can't access the fields of the timestamp without using the `dt` method. As for why I went through `isocalendar`, that is because `FutureWarning: Series.dt.weekofyear and Series.dt.week have been deprecated.  Please use Series.dt.isocalendar().week instead`

Comment: many thanks, I had noted the FutureWarning indeed when I tried on my own. this is an improvement, thank you again for your time!